# Difference in validation result when using saved model in Tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained a tensor flow model. After finishing the training epoch, I calculated the accuracy on the evaluation set and saved the model.
Now, It gives me difference in accuracy when I tried to recalculate on the validation set by loading the model(From the saved file).

I expected the same validation accuracy. I tried this in both tensorflow 1.x and tensorflow2.0.

Any pointers?

Comment: I tried the same with my sample datatset and did not find any differences. Please provide the code you are trying with to reproduce the error and fix it. Thanks!